# Where is the masterpage in 14 hive in sp 2010

Tags: master-page

I need to make a copy of the master page in sp 2010. where is it located? (I dont have SP Designer so that's not an option).

Answer (score 10):

It's in the 14 hive at:  C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS

Comment: r u certain? b/c there are no files with .master ext.

Comment: Yup, there's a v4.master in my layouts directory.

Comment: **careful** messing with these files. They belong to Microsoft, not you! Always take copies and work with those...

Answer (score 6):

You can navigate to the master page gallery via the root site Site Actions>Site Settings>(Galleries)Master pages and page layouts. Then select the master page file you want and click **Download a Copy** from the ribbon.

The url for the master page gallery is: http://server/_catalogs/masterpage